# How can I sort a v-data-table by default?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I can't seem to get default sorting to work. All I can see for the argument `custom-sort` in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) is that it's a "Function used to sort items", but I don't know in what way. I can imagine many. Is it called for an initial sort? It seems to return a list of items, but when I try to create one, I get an error saying `this.customSort is not a function`.

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="reports"
    hide-default-footer>
    <template v-slot:item.requested="{ item }">
      {{ datetimeToDistance(item.requested) }}
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
name: 'Reports',
data () {
    return {
        customSort: (items,index,isDesc) => console.log("never called"),
        reports: [{name:"a",requested:"2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"}.{name:"b",requested:"2020-02-02T00:00:00"}],
    }
},
computed: {
    headers () {
        return [
            {text: "Name", value: "name"},
            {text: "Report Type", value: "report_type"},
            {text: "Requested", value: "requested", sort: (a,b) => a.localeCompare(b) },
            ];
    },
}
}
</script>
```

My sorting works if you click on the links. All I really want here is to say: "When the page first loads, sort by 'requested' as though the user clicked that one initially. Then let them change the ordering."

Note: The `datetimeToDistance` is just a function which calls a library and isn't too important. It's just that the output of that column is not directly in the objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `sort-by` and the `sort-desc` properties with the `.sync` option, and set the desired values in data.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
      :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
    ></v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        sortBy: 'fat',
        sortDesc: false,
    },
  }
</script>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-sorting

Answer (score 5):

If using Vuetify 3.xx

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-data-table
            v-model:sort-by="sortBy"
        ></v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                sortBy: [{ key: 'key', order:'asc'}],
        },
    }
</script>
```

'key' should be the key you specified in the headers array

Comment: Thx for this. It seems to sort correctly but the table header doesnt indicate which column I've sorted on by default. Do you know how to achieve this? It would just be nice to immediately see which column is currently sorted when the table is first displayed..

Comment: @TobyFieldgroove
For me, an arrow is next the the header label to show that it is currently sorted. Maybe you could try to override the template for the headers to manually show the arrow if it is sorted?

Comment: You can use "const sortBy = ref([{ key: 'createdOn', order: 'desc' }])" for vue 3 in script setup.

Answer (score 2):

I usually sort v-datatable in the pagination directive as below:

```
<template>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="reports" :pagination.sync="pagination" hide-default-footer>
        <template v-slot:item.requested="{ item }">
            {{ datetimeToDistance(item.requested) }}
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Reports',
        data() {
            return {
                customSort: (items, index, isDesc) => console.log("never called"),
                reports: [{ name: "a", requested: "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z" }.{ name: "b", requested: "2020-02-02T00:00:00" }],
                pagination: { sortBy: 'requested', descending: true, rowsPerPage: 10 }
            }
        },
        computed: {
            headers() {
                return [
                    { text: "Name", value: "name" },
                    { text: "Report Type", value: "report_type" },
                    { text: "Requested", value: "requested", sort: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) },
                ];
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry but this is not really answering my question, is it? I am not paginating. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `pagination` is the name of the object which also holds sorting information. This is a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works too, it is how i do it:

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="headersItems"
          :items="items"
          :no-data-text="noData"
          :no-results-text="noResults"
          :sort-desc="true"
          sort-by="timestamp"

        >
```